# Application End after saving PDF file in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, nreco

I created one function which get HTML data from session and save that as PDF
for that I used `NReco.PdfGenerator`

```
private static string savePdf()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ReservationPrintHtml"] != null)
    {
        StringBuilder objStringBuilder = ((StringBuilder)HttpContext.Current.Session["ReservationPrintHtml"]);
        string dir = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Pdf");
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }
        string fileName = "PDF-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHMMssffffff") + ".pdf";
        string downloadFile = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
        string htmlContent = objStringBuilder.ToString();
        byte[] pdfBytes = (new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter()).GeneratePdf(htmlContent);
        File.WriteAllBytes(downloadFile, pdfBytes);
        return fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm not facing any issue regarding PDF generation but, After this function execution it directly calls `Application_End` in `Global.asax` 
I have tried if I get any error in application but `Application_Error` not execute.

Can anyone have idea what is the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search and googling I found that I'm saving files in `PDF` folder which was included in my project.
So whenever new PDF file was generated `AppDomain` `recycle` on folder change run after every `15-20` changes in folders which are included in solution included projects.
so I found solution by adding `fcnMode="Disabled"` in `web.cofig` file like below.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" fcnMode="Disabled" />
```